# Finding the parent class of a word in WordNet

Tags: python, wordnet

I want to find all the base classes of a word in WordNet.  (to present the hierarchy)

More specifically, if I have word, say `Persian cat`, how can I find all the relevant classes that lies above it in the hierarchy?

Comment: could you post some code that you have tried